# When combining needle package with async.auto, performance will degrade when there are a lot of concurrency requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

When combining needle package with async.auto, performance will degrade when there are a lot of concurrency requests

Given the codes below:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    async.auto({
        step1: function(cb) {
            console.log('step1');
            cb();
        },
        step2: ['step1', function(cb) {
            needle.get('https://www.google.com', function(err, response, body) {
                console.log('needle return');
            });
            cb();
        }]
    }, function(err) {
        res.json({
            'return': 'here'
        });
    });
});
```

I use the following command:

ab -n 100 -c 25 https://test.server.com/test

(Note: My test server is only single core cpu, 1GB RAM, running node.js, and nginx)

Most of the API response time are 500ms - 900ms

But if I have changed the codes to:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    async.series([
        function(cb) {
            console.log('step a');
            cb();
        },
        function(cb) {
            needle.get('https://www.google.com', function(err, response, body) {
                console.log('needle return');
            });
            console.log('step b');
            cb();
            res.json({
                'return': 'here'
            });
        }
    ]);
});
```

or if I have changed the codes to:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    async.auto({
        step1: function(cb) {
            console.log('step1');
            cb();
        },
        step2: ['step1', function(cb) {
            request('https://www.google.com', function(err, response, body) {
                console.log('http request return');
            });
            cb();
        }]
    }, function(err) {
        res.json({
            'return': 'here'
        });
    });
});
```

Most of the API response time are 10ms - 50ms, occasionally some requests are 100ms - 150ms

Do note that the performance differences are only obvious when there are a lot of concurrency requests to node.js (hence the ab benchmark)

Not sure if async.auto is not meant to work together with needle?
or there are other issues that I have overlooked?

I am using:

- https://github.com/caolan/async
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle
- node.js v0.10.37
- Ubuntu Linux (14.x)

Comment: Why do you call the `cb()` immediately, instead of when `needle` finishes???

Comment: In my application I just need to post data to another server, I don't need to wait for data from http response. But even if I put cb() when needle finishes, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answer by the needle package author

https://github.com/tomas/needle/issues/148